# Numbering rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops

i have a dataframe looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Marry', 'Victoria', 'Gabriel', 'Layla'],
    'last_name': ['Smith', 'Doe', 'Jackson', 'Smith', 'Brown', 'Martinez'],
    'number': [0, 29, 0, 52, 0, 0]})
```

And i am working on solution to numbering 0 values in Number column.
My code, with isnot working right

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[df['number'] == 0, 'number'] = i+1
df
```

This code replaces 0 with 1, but must replace first 0 with 1..second 0 with 2 etc...
i would like to have solution based on iteration method(.
Note: numbers "29", "52" etc, must not be changed

Answer (score 2):

Try [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) on a Boolean index based on `0` values in `df` then replace with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html#pandas-dataframe-cumsum) of the index to enumerate:

```
m = df['number'].eq(0)
df['number'] = np.where(m, m.cumsum(), df['number'])
```

Or use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html#pandas-series-mask)

```
m = df['number'].eq(0)
df['number'] = df['number'].mask(m, m.cumsum())
```

`df`:

```
  first_name last_name  number
0       John     Smith       1
1       Jane       Doe      29
2      Marry   Jackson       2
3   Victoria     Smith      52
4    Gabriel     Brown       3
5      Layla  Martinez       4
```

`m.cumsum()`:

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
Name: number, dtype: int32
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Marry', 'Victoria', 'Gabriel', 'Layla'],
    'last_name': ['Smith', 'Doe', 'Jackson', 'Smith', 'Brown', 'Martinez'],
    'number': [0, 29, 0, 52, 0, 0]
})

m = df['number'].eq(0)
df['number'] = np.where(m, m.cumsum(), df['number'])

print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try via boolean masking and `loc` accessor:

```
mask=df['number']==0   #created boolean mask

df.loc[mask,'number']=mask.cumsum()
```

**OR**

via `where()` method:

```
df['number']=df.where(~mask,mask.cumsum(),axis=0)['number']
```

**OR**

via boolean masking and `assign()` method

```
df[mask]=df[mask].assign(number=mask.cumsum())
```

Output of `df`:

```
  first_name last_name  number
0       John     Smith       1
1       Jane       Doe      29
2      Marry   Jackson       2
3   Victoria     Smith      52
4    Gabriel     Brown       3
5      Layla  Martinez       4
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative via `replace` and `fillna`:

```
df.number = df.number.replace(0,np.NAN).fillna(df.number.eq(0).cumsum())
```