# Numbering rows in pandas dataframe (with condition)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i ll already asked similar question, but i rethink my question and need to note, that i have to add conditions. (so i not sure if its ok to change my first post)
[Numbering rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67753543/numbering-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

i have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Marry', 'Victoria', 'Gabriel', 'Layla'],'last_name': ['Smith', 'Smith', 'Jackson', 'Smith', 'Brown', 'Martinez'],
    'number': [0, 29, 0, 0, 23, 0]
})
```

and i need to replace 0 values, but all of the "Smith" with 0 value must be count as similar "number"

my code

```
df2=df.groupby(['last_name','number']).min().reset_index() #grouping data based on last_name and number
mask=df2['number']==0   #created boolean mask
df2.loc[mask,'number']=mask.cumsum()
df2

#and than i must update zero values
df.merge(df2, on='last_name', how='left')
```

but something gone wrong...
may be there are is more clean solution?

UPDATE i need to split this persons by last names into different groups 'number'.
df have 3 different Smith: two with number 0 and one with 29.
As soon as other persons have 0 'number' ill grouped this persons by 'last_name' and then count this groups in 'number'.

Comment: What do you mean "i need to replace 0 values, but all of the "Smith" with 0 value must be count as similar "number""? Similar how? What is your expected output for the provided DataFrame?

Comment: i mean if there are is multiple persons with "smith" last_name, they must have similar "number"  \John  Smith  1\Jane  Smith  29\Victoria  Smith  1\ Marry  Jackson  2/ as example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-ngroup) + [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
df['number'] = np.where(
    df['number'].eq(0),
    df.groupby('last_name').ngroup(),
    df['number']
)
```

Or [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html#pandas-series-mask):

```
df['number'] = df['number'].mask(df['number'].eq(0),
                                 df.groupby('last_name').ngroup())
```

Or [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc):

```
df.loc[df['number'].eq(0), 'number'] = df.groupby('last_name').ngroup()
```

`df`:

```
  first_name last_name  number
0       John     Smith       3
1       Jane     Smith      29
2      Marry   Jackson       1
3   Victoria     Smith       3
4    Gabriel     Brown      23
5      Layla  Martinez       2
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Marry', 'Victoria', 'Gabriel', 'Layla'],
    'last_name': ['Smith', 'Smith', 'Jackson', 'Smith', 'Brown', 'Martinez'],
    'number': [0, 29, 0, 0, 23, 0]
})

df['number'] = np.where(
    df['number'].eq(0),
    df.groupby('last_name').ngroup(),
    df['number']
)

print(df)
```